# Answering my own question, but also kind of changing it

Tags: discussion, answers

I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/683875/80965) *troubling* question a few weeks ago, ever since then, and talking with other people, turns out that the problem is salvageable, but it has to be change to make sense. So I was wondering, should I just post the new version with the proof as an answer, if ever someone comes across it?, or should I post a new question and answer it myself?, what should I do?

Comment: The rule of thumb is: avoid transforming answerers' hard work into wasted time. There are probably exceptional circumstances, but let this guide you in most cases. Text is cheap: if your change is really substantial you can make it a separate question.

Comment: @rschwieb I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to post a new question, and then post an answer yourself. I would add a link to the previous question ("See also ..."), and in the old version, I would add at the end a link to the new one ("Related: ...").

Probably you will end up accepting your own answer, but I would wait a couple of days before doing that, in case someone else wants to contribute a different approach.

Also, in case there may be confusion, you may want in the body of the question to be explicit about how the new version you are posting is *not* a duplicate of the old one.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that, thanks. And also, I wasn't planning on accepting my answer, for two reasons: 1) it might be wrong `:P` and/or need improvement, and 2) I think it's weird. Is it necessary to accept it?

Comment: No, it is not necessary. But, if it is correct, and the best of the answers you receive, why not?

Answer (score 2):

Since   answers were already given to the original form of the question, you should not rewrite the question itself.

If you wish, you can post a self-answered question if you think the corrected version may be of interest to others. But check if it's not been asked before... most basic questions about    roots in the complex plane probably exist on the site already.

Comment: I think it has not been asked before, since I haven't been able to find it yet, however, one never knows...